# Consume messages in sequence. Topic 1 messages should be consumed before consumed from topic 2

Tags: spring-kafka

I have a scenario to consume the messages from topic 1 first and once all consumed from topic 1 then consume topic 2 messages. I used ContainerGroupSequencer as you mentioned in above comments.

As expected group 1 is stopped after receiving all messages and moved to group 2. But in my case I don't want to stop group1 after reading events. Just looking to read messages from topic 1 first and then topic2.

@KafkaListener(id = "listen3", topics = "topic1", containerGroup = "g1", concurrency = "2")
public void listen1(String in) {
}

@KafkaListener(id = "listen4", topics = "topic4=2", containerGroup = "g2", concurrency = "2")
public void listen2(String in) {
}

But using containerGroup property available for @@KafkaListener, it completely stops topic 1 kafka listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the first container yourself, using the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "myContainer", topics = "myTopic", autoStartup = "false")
public void listen(...) { ... }

@Autowired
private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

...

    this.registry.getListenerContainer("myContainer").start();

...
```